# create sequence of numbers from time dependent panel data

Tags: r, data-management, panel-data

so i have a data set where i have years students were in classes, and what quarter of the year they were in, so 2002 is 4 times and it has quarter 1,2,3,4, like below:

```
matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3),ncol=3,dimnames=list(c(NULL),c("ids","year","quarter")))
```

which gives me this

```
      ids year quarter
 [1,]   1 2002       1
 [2,]   1 2002       2
 [3,]   1 2002       3
 [4,]   1 2002       4
 [5,]   1 2003       1
 [6,]   1 2003       2
 [7,]   1 2003       3
 [8,]   2 2002       4
 [9,]   2 2002       1
[10,]   2 2002       2
[11,]   2 2002       3
[12,]   2 2003       4
[13,]   2 2003       1
[14,]   2 2003       2
[15,]   2 2003       3
```

i want to generate a sequence where it creates a new variable cumuluating the number of quarters, it wont be hard to merge year and quarter if i have to, but how do i tell it to do a sequence like

```
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), .Dim = c(15L, 4L
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ids", "year", "quarter", "sequence quarters"
)))
```

giving me this

```
      ids year quarter sequence quarters
 [1,]   1 2002       1                 1
 [2,]   1 2002       2                 2
 [3,]   1 2002       3                 3
 [4,]   1 2002       4                 4
 [5,]   1 2003       1                 5
 [6,]   1 2003       2                 6
 [7,]   1 2003       3                 7
 [8,]   2 2002       4                 1
 [9,]   2 2002       1                 2
[10,]   2 2002       2                 3
[11,]   2 2002       3                 4
[12,]   2 2003       4                 5
[13,]   2 2003       1                 6
[14,]   2 2003       2                 7
[15,]   2 2003       3                 8
```

i have tried rep command and sequence and such but i dont know how to tell it to restart the numbering after each participant. the number of quarters differs by student, and i dont need to know which quarter they start in, this is university data so they can start in quarter 2 i suppose (i haven't looked at the entire data set on the start values for all 6K participants or so) but i just need it to cumulate. i hope this question is appropriate and i formatted my question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ave` by `ids` and call `seq`:

```
 transform(dat , seqs = ave(dat[,'ids'],dat[,'ids'],FUN=seq))
 ids year quarter seqs
1    1 2002       1    1
2    1 2002       2    2
3    1 2002       3    3
4    1 2002       4    4
5    1 2003       1    5
6    1 2003       2    6
7    1 2003       3    7
8    2 2002       4    1
9    2 2002       1    2
10   2 2002       2    3
11   2 2002       3    4
12   2 2003       4    5
13   2 2003       1    6
14   2 2003       2    7
15   2 2003       3    8
```